# ¿Cómo recorrer un foreach en dos columnas?

Tags: php, html, laravel, bootstrap, foreach

Necesito saber cómo recorro un `foreach` para iterar en dos columnas, estoy generando un *pdf* a partir de ciertos datos, dichos datos los necesito ordenar en dos columnas con titulos y descripciones. a continuación daré un ejemplo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, les mostraré cómo me está imprimiendo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pasa que hay datos que no pertenecen a un titulo, y todos se imprimen de izquierda a derecha.

Aquí muestro el código de cómo estoy iterando.

```
@foreach ($htcuerpos->chunk(2) as $chunk)
<div class="row justify-content-center">
     @foreach ($chunk as $titulos)
        @if($titulos->visualizacion==true)
            <div class="col-xs-5">
              @if ($registro_id != $titulos->detalle()->first()->unidad()->first()->id)
                <strong id="unidad">  
             <p>{{$titulos->detalle()->first()->unidad()->first()->titulo}} </p> 
            </strong>      
              @php
              $registro_id=$titulos->detalle()->first()->unidad()->first()->id;
            @endphp 
      @endif
```

Quiero saber cómo organizarlo en dos columnas y que quede ordenadamente por favor. actualmente tengo otras validaciones pero lo importante es que pueda iterar en dos columnas y que no se desordene.

Answer (score 1):

creo que tu problema esta en la maquetacion, si lo haces así deberia verse como quieres

```
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <!-- Mitad de la derecha (desempeño) -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <!-- Mitad de la izquierda (propulsion)-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <!-- Mitad de la derecha (dimensiones) -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <!-- Mitad de la izquierda (auxiliares)-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <!-- Mitad de la derecha (capacidades) -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <!-- Mitad de la izquierda (navegacion y comunicaciones)-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <!-- Mitad de la derecha (area habitacional ) -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <!-- Mitad de la izquierda (armamento)-->
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: pero como lo iteraria para clasificar los titulos en dos columnas y abajo sus detalles? porque son dinamicos en eso he tenido problemas